# Can't Import Plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm on scala 2.13.1 and sbt 1.3.6 (not using most recent sbt since master branch specifies 1.3.6) and I can't get sbt-assembly from Maven Central. The relevant part of my build.sbt is below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")
```

It might also be relevant that IntelliJ marks every single one of my library dependencies as unresolved however I can use them and it compiles fine.

Edit: The specific text of the error is `not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.13_1.0/0.14.10/sbt-assembly-0.14.10.pom`
, as well as other errors looking across other resolvers.

Comment: That line should be on `./project/plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 0):

Per Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, that line should have been on plugins.sbt. Thank you.